# Finding Standings Table in a tournament

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, data-modeling

I have 2 tables

```
create table players
(name text,
 id serial primary key);

create table matches
 (winner integer references players(id),
  loser integer references players(id),
  id serial primary key);
```

I have to make a table called "standings" containing:

```
player_id,player_name,total_wins,total_matches
```

How to proceed?

Comment: You make another create table statement... Unclear how you are counting total wins and losses

Comment: Do you mean, you want a query returning a table with those columns and the obvious meanings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select p.id, p.name, 
       count(w.id) as total_wins, 
       count(l.id) + count(w.id) as total_matches
from players p 
  left join matches w on w.winner = p.id
  left join matches l on l.loser = p.id
group by p.id, p.name;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/EHDCG19917